# JavaScript-HTLM validation form not working properly. Python-bottle

Tags: javascript, python, html, bottle

I want to check if the email adress is already in my database using onfocusout in html. If the email adress exists then the messages shows me that the email exists when clicking out but when I rewrite another email adress the message disappears but when I click submit then the messages appears again and the button doesnt let me go to the next page even though I wrote a different email adress. The whole validation process goes to bottle-python route which delivers none if the email is not there or delivers the email if exists.

**The Email already exists in the database no problem:**
[image: The Email already exists in the database no problem]

**I wrote this and obviously doesnt exists and still gives me the message and doesnt let me click submit:**
[image: I wrote this and obviously doesnt exists and still gives me the message and doesnt let me click submit]

part of HTML + Javascript

'''

```
 <div class="box1">

  <form method="POST" id="form" name="form">
    <p>
        <label for="a">First Name:</label>
        <input id="a" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="b">Last Name:</label>
        <input id="b" type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Birthdate:</label>
        <input id="" type="date" name="birthD" placeholder="Date" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Adress:</label>
        <input id="" type="text" name="adress" placeholder="Adress" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">E-Mail Adress:</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@mail.com" onfocusout="checkIfUserExists()" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Phone:</label>
        <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Choose your form of Payment:</label>
        <select name="payment" required>
        <option option value="" disabled selected>Payment</option>
        <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
        <option value="Debit">Debit</option>
        <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </p>

</form>


<div class="box11">
    
</div>
```

```
 </div>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  const  checkIfUserExists = () => {
     const   registrationForm = document.forms['form']
     const emailFormElement = registrationForm['email']
     const email = emailFormElement.value
  
     axios.post('/validate_email',{ //goes to bottle python
     email: email           //
    })
   .then((response) => {
     if (response.data.user_exists == "true") {
            emailFormElement.setCustomValidity("This email adress already exist")
            emailFormElement.checktValidity()

     }
     else {

     }


   }, (error) => {
     console.log(error)

  })


 }
 </script>
```

'''
Route validates if the email is in database
'''

```
 @route('/validate_email', method=['POST'])
 def validate_email():
    
  if request.method == 'POST':
    email_adress = request.json['email'] #the values comes from javascript
    email = emailextraction(email_adress)
    print(email)
    if email:  
            return {"user_exists": "true"} #this goes back to javascript
    else: 
            return {"user_exists": "false"}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

First for all in your html file correct the type of email input tag it's written `emial` should be `email`.

Secondly, you should provide the email in correct format following `RFC 5322 and 6854`.

Actually the second time you change it to a random email(here you have entered it in wrong format) which is not in the database. Actually the `checkIfUserExists()` functions passes perfectly but the HTML email input tag reports a wrong email format.

Since you have changed the validity message by this line
`emailFormElement.setCustomValidity("This email address already exists);`.

HTML tries to notify about the incorrect format but it is forced to use `email already exists` message because it's explicitly set in your code.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error and I changed emailFormElement.checkValidity()  to emailFormElement.reportValidity()

Comment: @ed190 have you entered correct email format and correct the type attribute of input tag?